# Calling .Net function asking for System.Type parameter in ColdFusion

Tags: c#, .net, api, coldfusion

I am attempting to integrate with the Xero API via a [C# Library](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net) in my ColdFusion site. I have managed to create a few different objects using

```
createObject(".net","Xero.<i>class</i>","XeroAPI.DLL")
```

and have managed to make a few calls against the different objects, however I'm having an issue with one of the calls. Doing a cfdump on the repository object shows a function called

```
UpdateOrCreate__1(System.Type, XeroApi.Model.ModelBase)
```

which is used as a generic function for uploading data to Xero. I have managed to create the object that I want to upload fine, however I'm not sure what to put in the System.Type parameter. I assumed it would just be a string or something similar defining the class of the object, however when I try this

```
oXeroRepository.UpdateOrCreate__1("XeroApi.Model.Employee",oXeroEmployee);
```

I get the error

> *Either there are no methods with the specified method name and
>   argument types or the `UpdateOrCreate__1` method is overloaded with
>   argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion
>   found 0 methods that match the provided arguments*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you need a fully qualified type name? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx

Comment: Why aren't you using the rest services xero provides?

Comment: The main reason is that we were hoping to avoid having to write our own implementation of oAuth and integrating with the API. This is a short-term solution while we work on a long term solution as a separate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through many pages on the web I noticed a function on one of the code examples called getDotNetClass(). Calling this function on the .Net object I was passing up to the C# library did the trick.

Comment: Assuming SO is not making you wait ;), do not forget to mark your follow-up as the answer.